# Integral of exponential function with power

Tags: integration

I would like to know if somebody has an insight about how to evaluate these 2 integrals:
$$ F(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^\beta-sx}dx $$
$$ I = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha (x+t) ^\beta - q x^\beta}dxdt$$
with $\alpha,\beta, q > 0$.

These two involve in a calculation of a probability distribution. Of course I can conserve this form and have it done numerically but I wonder if we can obtain something nice?

Thanks in advance for responses!

Comment: I would probably specific what exactly you mean by "evaluate",   in terms of what? Are you looking for widely used special functions that might be able to express $F$ or do you want something else?

Comment: Yes what I am looking for is some special function which can help express $F$ without the integral. For instance, computing (change of variable) the integral $ \int _0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^\beta}dx$ could result in a Gamma function $\Gamma(1/\beta+1)$ but since I have an extra term $-sx$ in the power, it is tricky and I can't figure out how to do it.